# How to handle exception generated from Rack before reaching your rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, rack

I have a jruby rails application running under tomcat.  Some malformed query string in url cause Rack to choke with the exception stack trace being shown in production mode.  Is there a way to handle that gracefully.  I don't think I can use config.exception_app as that will only handle exception generated from  the rails app.  In this case, the exception is generated before it get to the rails app.  Here is the exception:

```
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (ArgumentError) invalid %-encoding (/"{}\%#$())
    at Module.decode_www_form_component(jar:file:/usr/local/apache-
tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/gems-gems-jruby-jars-1.7.3-lib-jruby-stdlib-
1.7.3.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.9/uri/common.rb:898)
    at Rack::Utils.unescape(/usr/local/apache-tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-
INF/gems/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/utils.rb:41)
    at Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(/usr/local/apache-tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-
INF/gems/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/utils.rb:94)
    at org.jruby.RubyArray.map(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2361)
    at Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(/usr/local/apache-tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-
INF/gems/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/utils.rb:94)
    at org.jruby.RubyArray.each(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613)
    at Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(/usr/local/apache-tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-
INF/gems/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/utils.rb:93)
    at Rack::Request.parse_query(/usr/local/apache-tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-
INF/gems/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/request.rb:332)
    at Rack::Request.POST(/usr/local/apache-tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-
INF/gems/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/request.rb:209)
    at Rack::MethodOverride.method_override(/usr/local/apache-
tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:26)
    at Rack::MethodOverride.call(/usr/local/apache-tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-
INF/gems/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:14)
    at Rack::Runtime.call(/usr/local/apache-tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-
INF/gems/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17)
    at ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware.call(/usr/local/apache-
tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72)
    at Rack::Lock.call(/usr/local/apache-tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-
INF/gems/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15)
    at Rack::Cache::Context.forward(/usr/local/apache-tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-
INF/gems/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136)
    at Rack::Cache::Context.pass(/usr/local/apache-tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-
INF/gems/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:143)
    at Rack::Cache::Context.invalidate(/usr/local/apache-tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-
INF/gems/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:155)
    at Rack::Cache::Context.call!(/usr/local/apache-tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-
INF/gems/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:71)
    at Rack::Cache::Context.call(/usr/local/apache-tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-
INF/gems/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51)
    at Rails::Engine.call(/usr/local/apache-tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-
INF/gems/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:479)
    at Rails::Application.call(/usr/local/apache-tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-
INF/gems/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:223)
    at Rack::Handler::Servlet.call(file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-
INF/lib/gems-gems-jruby-rack-1.1.13.1-lib-jruby-rack-
1.1.13.1.jar!/rack/handler/servlet.rb:22)
```

Comment: the default in java land is to configure a 500 template in your application server aka your tomcat

Comment: I ended up just writing a rack middleware to intercept the exception and handle it.

Answer (score 0):

if the Ruby runtime is booted - which in this case seems it is ... you should be able to configure a (minimal) rack error application just set smt rack-y (`require 'my_error_app'; run MyErrorApp`) into the **jruby.rack.error.app** context parameter (e.g. in your *web.xml* with Warbler)

Comment: Can you share more information on this?  I am not able to find example on how to do that.  How to write an rack error application and how to use the jruby.rack.error.app context parameter.  Jruby-rack github page doesn't seem to have explanation on jruby.rack.error.app

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a rack middleware to handle the exception gracefully. I insert the middleware before MethodOverride middleware which is where it throws the exception.